# Change Shape Fill based on Shape Data in Visio

Tags: visio, shapesheet

Wondering if someone can help me with what I thought was a simple Shapesheet issue.

I'd like the fill colour of a shape to change based on one of the shape data values. I thought I could do this easily:

FillForeground: If(Prop.Colour="Blue",XXX,YYY)

But this doesn't work? (Visio 2021)

I've 5 list values for the data and would like a different fill colour for each? Weirdly, I can see that the value does change based on the data selection, but the actual colour seen in on the page doesn't.

Obviously, I'm not much of a coder, just an enthusiastic meddler.

I've stuck at:

=IF(Sheet.3780!Prop.StringSection="Firsts",THEMEGUARD(MSOTINT(THEME("LineColor"),40)),THEMEGUARD(MSOTINT(THEME("AccentColor"),40)))

(The shapes to colour are within a group)

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Steve !

> FillForeground: If(Prop.Colour="Blue",XXX,YYY)
>
> But this doesn't work? (Visio 2021)

For compare strings in ShapeSheet you must use [STRSAME function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/strsame-function)
Use syntax like this:

```
IF(STRSAME(Prop.color,"blue"),4,3)
```

Comment: May be this article can helps: [Choose Colors with Shape Data Fields](http://www.visguy.com/2009/10/21/choose-colors-with-shape-data-fields/)